# Export Custom List to Excel using Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, custom-list

I am running Sharepoint Online and have a question about Export to Excel using a workflow.

I currently have an Approval workflow that is initiated when the user fills out their web form. I want to be able to export this data to an excel spreadsheet once the request is approved.

I can't seem to find anything on how to do this, there are tons of Export Custom List to Excel questions online but none that seem to actually address my issue.

Please let me know if you have any clarifying questions!

Update:

I've used the "Export to Excel" feature to create a data connection.  That will work for getting the information into excel but once the data is there I will need one last user to change a field from "New" to "Complete" on every field that says new on the list.  Is there a way to workflow changes to multiple data list entries at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question, but isn't the Export to excel button available on your custom list? I find the button on my newly created custom list in my SharePoint Online environment. It's located in the connect and export section.

[image]

When exported to excel you can keep the data synchronized and up to date when anything happens in the custom SharePoint list.

Comment: Yes, it is available.  Maybe I am misunderstanding how the linked excel document works.  Would changes made in the document sync back to the list as well as new changes being synced to the spreadsheet?  If that is the case then problem solved.  If not, I was trying to create a workflow that once the information is exported changes a list field.  Make sense?

Comment: @Benjooster It's unidirectional only. Changes in the list will sync to the spreadsheet, but not the other way around.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it and realized that.  Is there a way to make a workflow change a text box or drop down field from "new" to "complete" for the entire list?  Don't want to run the workflow for each item on the list, but need excel to update the changes so that it can create a csv for accounting.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue of trying to run an Excel export from a filtered list as part of a workflow. The list gets populated over the course of a month and then I want to export everything which has been approved since the 25th of the previous month. Unfortunately I have not come across an automated export which easily works for Nintex Workflows.